# Using controller in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Angular newbie here. I am trying [Brian's example of importing data into UI Grid from Excel](http://brianhann.com/easily-import-spreadsheets-into-ui-grid/). This works like a charm. Brian uses a custom directive. I am able to read the excel file perfectly. After reading excel data in the directive i want to check the excel data columns with the existing UI-grid table in the controller. After confirming that all the columns are present in the excel i need to save it in my database.

To do that, I am not able to access gridApi from the directive. Not sure where i am going wrong. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here's the simplified version of the code which just logs the GridApi / any Scope variable ( from controller) in the directive.

**app.js**

```
var crApp_WCF = angular.module('crApp_WCF', ['ngRoute', 'crApp_WCF_Ctrls', 'crServices', 'ui.grid', 'crApp_WCF_Drtvs', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.selection']);
```

**controller.js**

```
var crApp_WCF_Ctrls = angular.module('crApp_WCF_Ctrls', ['crServices', 'ui.grid.exporter']);

crApp_WCF_Ctrls.controller('crHomeCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope, $http, uiGridConstants, CrCRUD, uiGridExporterService, uiGridExporterConstants) {
$scope.crGrid = {
$scope.crGrid.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
columnDefs: [
     { name: 'OppName', field: 'OppName', enableFiltering: false, minWidth: 100, headerTooltip: true, enableCellEdit: false },
            { name: 'AcCode', field: 'AcCode', enableFiltering: false, minWidth: 60, headerTooltip: true, enableCellEdit: false },
            ]}
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    };
```

**directives.js**

```
var crApp_WCF_Drtvs = angular.module('crApp_WCF_Drtvs', ['crApp_WCF_Ctrls']);

crApp_WCF_Drtvs.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
controller: 'crHomeCtrl',
       scope: {
            gridApi: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs, $rootScope) {
            $elm.on('change', function (changeEvent) {

                     Console.log(($scope.gridApi) //displays Undefined; I want the gridApi from the controller to be displayed here.
});
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="crHomeCtrl">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="exportXLSX()">Export as XLSX</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showImport=true">Import from excel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="showImport=false" ng-show="showImport">Close</button>
        <br />
        <br />

        <div ui-grid="crGrid" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-selection class="CrGrid">
            <div class="grid-msg-overlay" ng-show="showImport">
                <div class="msg">
                    <div class="center">
                        <span class="muted">Select Spreadsheet File</span>
                        <br />
                        <input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods" fileread opts="vm.gridOptions" multiple="false" />
                        <br/>
                        {{msg}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution no. 1:
why not inject the `controller` instead in `link` function. This returns the parent controller of the directive where it was placed.

```
crApp_WCF_Drtvs.directive("fileread", [function () {
  return {
   scope: {
        gridApi: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs, controller) {
      $elm.on('change', function (changeEvent) {

        // console.log(controller.gridApi);
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Solution no. 2:
You already set `scope: { gridApi: '=' }` why not make use of it.

```
// JS
crApp_WCF_Drtvs.directive("fileread", [function () {
  return {
   scope: {
        gridApi: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
      $elm.on('change', function (changeEvent) {

        // console.log($scope.gridApi);
      });
    }
  }
}]);

// HTML
<input type="file"
       accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods"
       fileread
       opts="vm.gridOptions"
// give gridApi scope variable for fileread directive to get
       grid-api="gridApi"
       multiple="false" />
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you @masterpreenz! i used your second solution. Instead of gridapi, i used opts and it worked. I had to change the opts="vm.gridOptions" to opts="crGrid" to make it working. That's where i had gone wrong! :)